# ASP.NET подсчет общего дохода подкомпаний

Tags: алгоритм, asp.net, рекурсия

У меня есть TreeView с компаниями. Каждая компания может иметь дочерные компании каждая дочерная компания может иметь свом дочерные компании и это может продолжаться до бесконечности. У каждой компании есть собственные доходы, и еще есть fullEarnings которое равняется сумме всех доходов дочерных компаний этой компании.

Мне нужно рассчитать прибыль для каждой компании, если известно собственный заработок каждой компании.

Пример:

[image: Пример подсчета]

У меня есть столбец  ParentID в базе данных, значения которого ссылаются на идентификатор родительской компании.

Как я могу это сделать? Может быть, с помощью рекурсии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, например, вот так.

```
private List<TreeViewNode> _GetFullBranch(TreeViewNode node)
{
   List<TreeViewNode> list = new List<TreeViewNode> { node };
   foreach (var child in node.Items)
      list.AddRange(_GetFullBranch(child as TreeViewNode));

   return list;
}
```